# Accidentally import the MySQL user table into TiDB, or forget the password

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

If I accidentally import the MySQL user table into TiDB, or forget the password and cannot log in, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the TiDB service, add the `-skip-grant-table=true` parameter in the configuration file. Log into the cluster without password and recreate the user, or recreate the `mysql.user` table using the following statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST mysql.user;

CREATE TABLE if not exists mysql.user (
    Host        CHAR(64),
    User        CHAR(16),
    Password      CHAR(41),
    Select_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Insert_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Update_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Delete_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Create_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Drop_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Process_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Grant_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    References_priv     ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Alter_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Show_db_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Super_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Create_tmp_table_priv   ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Lock_tables_priv    ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Execute_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Create_view_priv    ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Show_view_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Create_routine_priv   ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Alter_routine_priv    ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Index_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Create_user_priv    ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Event_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    Trigger_priv      ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY (Host, User));

INSERT INTO mysql.user VALUES ("%", "root", "", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y");
```